# Cron job openshift error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cron, openshift

I have a rails 4 openshift application.  I am trying to run a cron job.  The script runs completely fine when I run it by itself.  The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production "Payment.charge_customers_pay_experts"'
```

The problem is the log file gives me the following error

```
Wed Feb  3 22:57:05 EST 2016: START minutely cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
/var/lib/openshift/56a438107628e18b30000111/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/åcron/minutely/charge_customers_pay_experts:
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
/var/lib/openshift/56a438107628e18b30000111/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/sid.rb:39:in `getpgid': Permission denied (Errno::EACCES)
from /var/lib/openshift/56a438107628e18b30000111/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/sid.rb:39:in `pgid'
from /var/lib/openshift/56a438107628e18b30000111/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/server.rb:78:in `set_pgid'
from /var/lib/openshift/56a438107628e18b30000111/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/server.rb:34:in `boot'
from /var/lib/openshift/56a438107628e18b30000111/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/server.rb:14:in `boot'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
__________________________________________________________________________
Wed Feb  3 22:57:06 EST 2016: END minutely cron run - status=0
__________________________________________________________________________
```

I have made sure the script was executable.  I'm not sure if I am missing something.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by commenting out the 'spring' gem in my gemfile.  But apparently this is a known issue. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1305544.

There is a workaround for the time being until this issue is resolved. You can edit the /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh to add `setsid` in front of `timeout` so that it runs `setsid timeout ...` as this allows for the timeout command to actually change the sid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the script being executable necessarily has anything to do with this.  It looks like a permissions error more than anything.  Does the system user that runs the cron job have the correct permissions to run?  You can test this by logging into that user (or `sudo su - <user>`) and then execute the command in the script manually.

`/bin/bash -l -c 'cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production "Payment.charge_customers_pay_experts"'`

Be sure to replace your `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` variable with the correct path to your OpenShift repo directory.

You may just need to either add the user your cronjob runs as to the group that has permissions over the files, or perhaps run the cronjob as a more privileged user (privileged in that it has permissions over the required files).

BTW, I could only post this as an answer as Stack Overflow is telling me I need 50 reputation points to comment.